# Explanation of lambda functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, lambda

what is the `x` doing at the end? Why do I need to write it there?

```hs
(\x -> (>=5) x)
```

If I am calling the function like this: `(\x -> (>=5) x) 5`, what is the second x doing?
Maybe someone can explain this to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `(>= 5)` is a [*section of an infix operator* <sup>[Haskell-wiki]</sup>](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator), it is equivalent to `\y -> y >= 5`, it is thus a function, and we apply `x` to that function. This thus means that:

```
\x -> (>= 5) x
```

is thus equivalent to:

```
\x -> x >= 5
```

or simply:

```
(>= 5)
```

due to [*η-reduction* <sup>[Haskell-wiki]</sup>](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion).